# Predefined Text is not loading

Tags: text

I am trying to Provide an option for user to edit the **preloaded text** as below image :

I gave an option to add the **New text** to user using below code, but **Preloaded text is not displaying** [KAYLE JACKSON] in my case

**Html**

```
<div entity_id="52912" style="left: 97.5px; top: 26.9915px; ">
    <textarea style="font-family: open_sans_condensedbold;">
    </textarea>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
var cardConfig = "fields":[{"id":52912,"text":"K A Y L E E   J A C K S O N","align":"center","font":"open_sans_condensedbold","color":"ffffff","rotation":0.0000000000,"size":22.6100000000,"x":92.2500000000,"y":28.9400000000}];

if (editorMode == "cards" || editorMode == "ecards") {
    $('#overlay_front_card').show().append($('<img>').attr('src', cardConfig.thumbnail));
}
if (cardConfig.pages !== null) {
    //CARD ORIGINAL DESIGN
    for (card_idx = 0; card_idx < cardConfig.pages.length; card_idx++) {
        var textFields = cardConfig.pages[card_idx].fields;
        $(textFields).each(function () {
            if ($.inArray(this.font, fontNames) < 0) {
                fontNames.push(getFontName(this.font));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy as i need to add multiple images, json and other external js files, i could't able to make jsfiddle, so only i posted links, please check once....

Comment: You could make the effort of creating a minimal version of your problem, that's what we all do.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy i need to post all these [files](http://139.59.24.243/ecom1/green8/Multi%20Photo%20-%20Birthday%20Invitation%20Template%20(free)%20_%20Greetings%20Island_files/) in fiddle,  i tried to make with code snippet and jsfiddle, but both dont support those many files.... please tell me is there any other online tool ?

Comment: I"ll repeat what I said. You need to create a ***minimal*** version of your *problem*. And not recreate all of your website. Please read [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I don't know the solution yet but you have a syntax error on line 1 in your code with an unexpected :

Comment: Try removing the : right after fields and check your code syntax.

Comment: @hiew1 Thanks for suggestion, are you telling in console ? i am not getting in which line ? can you please tell me code ?

Comment: This line var cardConfig = "fields":[{"id":52912,"text":"K A Y L E E   J A C K S O N","align":"center","font":"open_sans_condensedbold","color":"ffffff","rotation":0.0000000000,"size":22.6100000000,"x":92.2500000000,"y":28.9400000000}];

Comment: @hiew1 means dont i need : after ` "fields": ` ?

Comment: The syntax is not right. If I remove the : after the "fields" it seems to make the syntax error go away.

Comment: If you have syntax error in your code your script won't work. So that's one of the very first things you should check in your code.

Comment: @hiew1 thanks,  i removed : after fields, but that did't helped me.....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186914/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-hiew1).

Comment: Can't you achieve it simply by giving value to the textarea?

Comment: @vishulgarg I tried that, but not worked ,please join https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186914/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-hiew1